# How do I check if one element in an array satisfies a pattern, while the rest don't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, conditional-statements

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I know how to check if a string is all capitalized by doing

```
str == str.upcase
```

but if I have an array of strings, what is a quick way to check that only the last element of the array is capitalized while, for the other elements,  str != str.upcase .  I'm assuming there is at least one element in the array and if there is only one element and it is capitalized, I would want my condition to evaluate to true.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We'd like to see your attempt so we can correct it. You've only given us a list of requirements so it looks like you want us to write the code for you.

Comment: You might want to replace the word "capitalized" with something like "contains only capital letters", since "capitalized" refers to only the first character of a word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def only_last_upcase?(arr)
  arr.find_index { |w| w == w.upcase } == arr.size - 1
end

only_last_upcase? ["word", "wOrD", "WORD"] #=> true
only_last_upcase? ["WORD", "wOrD", "WORD"] #=> false
only_last_upcase? ["word", "wOrD", "word"] #=> false
only_last_upcase? ["word"]                 #=> false
only_last_upcase? ["Word"]                 #=> false
only_last_upcase? ["WORD"]                 #=> true
only_last_upcase? []                       #=> false
```

Comment: Very clever! I became ashamed of my answer now :)

Comment: You need to fix your regex: `only_last_upcase?(['Word']) #=> true`

Comment: Thanks, @Michael. I didn't read the question very carefully. I guess I saw the word "capitalized" and went from there. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Slightly more concise: `arr.find_index { |str| str == str.upcase } == arr.size - 1`

Comment: @Stefan, yes, that's better. Thanks. I've edited to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `find_index` passes elements to the block, not indices.

Comment: @Stefan, yes, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The good thing about Ruby is that it's fairly easy to turn textual descriptions of problems into actual code:

```
def only_last_upcase?(arr)
  last_index = arr.size - 1
  arr.find_index { |s| s =~ /^[A-Z]*$/ } == last_index
end
```

Both of them have the following results:

```
only_last_upcase?(["word", "wOrD", "WORD"])
#=> true
only_last_upcase?(["WORD", "wOrD", "WORD"])
#=> false
only_last_upcase?(["word", "wOrD", "word"])
#=> false
only_last_upcase?(["word"])
#=> false
only_last_upcase?(["WORD"])
#=> true
only_last_upcase?([])
#=> false
```

Comment: Your first version compares each element to the last element, so it returns `true` for `["FOO", "BAR", "BAZ"]`. Besides, `none?` doesn't necessarily traverse the whole array, it returns as soon as the block returns a truthy result.

Comment: 2 very good points @Stefan, serves me right for posting answers on SO right after waking up.

Comment: I just completely removed the first version.

Answer (score 1):

Check only **one** element satisfies your condition **and** that the array's **last** element satisfies the same condition:

```
arr.one? { |str| str == str.upcase } && arr.last == arr.last.upcase
```

Passes all the same tests given in the answer by Cary Swoveland.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
def check_only_last_upcase(arr)
    return false if arr.empty?
    arr.each_with_index do |word, index| 
        return false if word == word.upcase && index != (arr.length-1)
    end
    (arr.last.upcase == arr.last)
end

puts check_only_last_upcase(["word", "wOrD", "WORD"]) #true
puts check_only_last_upcase(["WORD", "wOrD", "WORD"]) #false
puts check_only_last_upcase(["word", "wOrD", "word"]) #false
puts check_only_last_upcase(["word"]) #false
puts check_only_last_upcase(["WORD"]) #true
puts check_only_last_upcase([]) #false
```

Another way (looks more like a ruby way?):

```
def check_only_last_upcase(arr)
    arr.last == arr.last.upcase &&
    arr
        .slice(0,arr.length-1)
        .all? { |word| word.upcase != word }
end
```

Last suggestion assumes `arr` has always at least one item (don't return if `arr` is empty), as you pointed.

Answer (score 0):

Or, possibly:

```
foo.last == foo.last.upcase and foo.select{|e| e == foo.last}.length == 1
```

And...

```
2.3.1 :001 > foo = ["WORD","Word"]
 => ["WORD", "Word"] 
2.3.1 :002 > foo.last == foo.last.upcase and foo.select{|e| e == foo.last}.length == 1
 => false 
2.3.1 :003 > foo = ["WORD","WORD"]
 => ["WORD", "WORD"] 
2.3.1 :004 > foo.last == foo.last.upcase and foo.select{|e| e == foo.last}.length == 1
 => false 
2.3.1 :005 > foo = ["Word","WORD"]
 => ["Word", "WORD"] 
2.3.1 :006 > foo.last == foo.last.upcase and foo.select{|e| e == foo.last}.length == 1
 => true 
2.3.1 :007 > foo = ["Word","WORD","WORD"]
 => ["Word", "WORD", "WORD"] 
2.3.1 :008 > foo.last == foo.last.upcase and foo.select{|e| e == foo.last}.length == 1
 => false 
2.3.1 :009 > foo = ["WORD"]
 => ["WORD"] 
2.3.1 :010 > foo.last == foo.last.upcase and foo.select{|e| e == foo.last}.length == 1
 => true 
2.3.1 :011 > foo = ["Word"]
 => ["Word"] 
2.3.1 :012 > foo.last == foo.last.upcase and foo.select{|e| e == foo.last}.length == 1
 => false
```